# Access 2013 - Quickest way to read in Excel data

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Part of my Access code is to read in data from an existing excel file.  I've been able to figure out how to do it, but it takes a long time to process.  The excel file has around 400 rows and I am just grabbing the data from two columns and placing it into a multidimensional array.

```
Dim excelapp As Excel.Application
Dim strBxNum As String: strBxNum = "bx" & strInd
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Set excelapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim WkBk As Excel.Workbook
Set WkBk = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(fileName:=strFileName)

i = 6
r = 0

Do While WkBk.Sheets(3).Range("C" & i) <> ""
  strWriteUp(r, 0) = WkBk.Sheets(3).Range("C" & i)
  strWriteUp(r, 1) = WkBk.Sheets(3).Range("P" & i)

  i = i + 1
  r = r + 1
Loop
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What's the end goal? What do you do with the array? Access can directly read workbooks within queries!

Comment: It would probably be way faster to link the worksheet in Access as a linked table. Then read this using code to filter for the requested data. Without sample data it is difficult to be more specific.

Comment: The end goal is to do a compare of two spreadsheets for differences.  After reading your two comments, I got the feeling there is a much better way to go about it.  I'm fairly new to VBA, could you provide a link to these other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell-by-cell operations tend to be much slower than using an array to read a range in one shot (particularly across application boundaries).

E.g.

```
Dim excelapp As Excel.Application
Dim strBxNum As String: strBxNum = "bx" & strInd
Dim i As Long, lr As Long
Dim WkBk As Excel.Workbook, arrC, arrP

Set excelapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set WkBk = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(fileName:=strFileName)

i = 6

With WkBk.Sheets(3)
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    arrC = .Range(.cells(i, "C"), .Cells(lr, "C") ).Value
    arrP = .Range(.cells(i, "P"), .Cells(lr, "P") ).Value
End With
```

That will give you two 1-based 2-D arrays (1 to #rows, 1 to 1) which you can either use as-is, or loop over and combine into a single 2-D array.

**EDIT** Put arrP into arrC:

```
Dim n As Long, nR as Long

nR = ubound(arrC, 1)
ReDim Preserve arrC(1 to nR, 1 to 2)
For n = 1 to nR
    arrC(n, 2) = arrP(n, 1)
next n
```

Comment: That does run quicker.  So I tried to just check to be sure the data was getting into the array with a simple "MsgBox arrP(2)" line, but get a "subscript out of range" error on that line.  I did a UBound and the array size looks good, but not sure why I cant check the data.

Comment: `MsgBox arrP(2,1)` - it's a 2-D array.

Comment: Okay, I did try...but unable to figure out how to "loop over and combine into a single 2-D array".